# Checking for a file on the desktop in VB

Tags: vb.net, file, search, shortcut

Is there anyway of searching for a file (shortcut file) on the desktop in VB? 
I've tried :
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("Desktop\MYFILE.lnk")
doesnt return anything

If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("Desktop\MYFILE.exe")
doesnt return anything

If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop\MYFILE.lnk")
doesnt return anything

If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop\MYFILE.exe")
doesnt return anything

I have searched for this too on google can't seem to find anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you question has just been type incorrectly, and forgive my VB skills, but should it not be:

```
> If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\MYFILE.lnk")
> Then
>     ' Do Something
> End
```

C# I would use:

```
if(System.IO.File.Exists(string.format("{0}{1}", Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), @"\MYFILE.lnk")))
{
  // do something with file
}
```

Comment: Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop & "\MYFILE.lnk" returns "0\MYFILE.lnk".My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop & "\MYFILE.lnk") returns False even if the shortcut exists. Need to use the solution suggested by @Yatrix ... System.IO.File.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\MYFILE.lnk"

Comment: @Guru Josh - Yes you are correct, I wrote this that long ago and did not pick up that mistake as the SpecialFolder is just an enumeration I believe

Answer (score 1):

```
System.IO.File.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\MYFILE.exe")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function DesktopShortcutExists(ByVal sShortCutName As String) As Boolean
    Dim sPublicPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory) & "\" & sShortCutName & ".lnk"
    Dim sUserPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) & "\" & sShortCutName & ".lnk"
    Return File.Exists(sPublicPath) = True Or File.Exists(sUserPath) = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it like this:

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\myfile.lnk")
```

Basically I just want to know if you are making sure that your string concatenation is correct, and using the \ when necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, however, this question already has an answer and it's 3 years old, when posting please try not to revive very old threads. Regards